# How to HTTP POST a Flux<String> as a JSON array using Spring's WebClient?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

How do I use Spring's reactive `WebClient` to POST a `Flux<String>` as a JSON array?

```
Flux<String> stringFlux = Flux.fromIterable(objects).map(MyObject::getSomeString);

WebClient.create(baseUrl)
  .post()
  .uri(myUrl)
  .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  .body(stringFlux, String.class)
  .exchange()
  .flatMap(response -> {
     if (response.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
       // Do something
     }
     return response.bodyToMono(Void.class);
   })
   .block();
```

This sends the request, but it's not sending it as a JSON array of strings.

I saw that there's another `body()` signature that accepts a `ParameterizedTypeReference`, so I tried this:

`.body(stringFlux.collectList(), new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {})`

but this results in a compile error actually (I'm on Java 11):

`Error:java: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$FunctionDescriptorLookupError`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I'll be darned.  I got it working using `ParameterizedTypeReference`.  As is usually the case, the compile error sums it up.  I omitted the type parameter when declaring a `new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {}`.  Providing the type did the trick and posted my `Flux<String>` as a JSON array:

`.body(stringFlux.collectList(), new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {})`

IntelliJ was telling me this type was inferred, but apparently it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without `ParametrizedTypeRefrence` using `List.class` is enough for Strings.

```java
.body(stringFlux.collectList(), List.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

The voted solution doesn't seem to produce the mentioned result. This seems to stream a list of JSON objects (which is what Webclient is intended for) rather than sending a JSON Array structure.
the result I get with that technic is :

```
{}{}{}{}
```

A JSON Array output would be:

```
[{}, {}, {}, {}]
```

Unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

```
.body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(stringFlux))
```

Not sure if this is the right answer.
It works for me to send List<> as body